# Problem in removing a conda created environment

Tags: python

I installed tensorflow using `conda create -n tf-gp tensorflow-gpu`.
Then I activated it using: `conda activate tf-gpu`
Then I uninstalled `tensorflow` from this environment using:`conda uninstall tensorflow`

Then I installed `tensorflow` on the `base` environment using: `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu`. that installed `tensorflow-gpu-1.13.1`.

Then I imported `python` and checked if `tensorflow` has been installed or not uisng `tensorflow.version` and I got the following message:

`<module 'tensorflow._api.v1.version' from '/home/..../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v1/version/__init__.py'>`

Then I uninstalled it using `conda remove tensorflow-gpu`, I uninstalled tensorflow.

Then I tried to install it using `pip` via the following command:
`pip install --upgrade pip pip install tensorflow`

Then I checked if `tensorflow` has bben installed using `pip` or not by the following command:
`pip freeze`

Then I tried reinstall `tensorflow` using:
`conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu`

Bot the following error drooped out:
`WARNING: A conda environment already exists at '/home/..../anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu' Remove existing environment (y/[n])? y`

And at the end I got the error:
`Proceed ([y]/n)? y Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: failed NoSpaceLeftError: No space left on devices.`

and when I checked if it has already been installed I got the following message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`
So, I tried to reinstall it using:

`conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu`

but I got the following error:

WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location '/home/..../anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu'
but it is not a conda environment.
Continue creating environment (y/[n])? y`

When I choose `y` I got the following error:
`CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /home/..../anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu`

When I try to create a new_env using:

`conda create --name new_env tensorflow-gpu`

Then I got the following error:

`CondaError: Unable to create prefix directory '/home/..../anaconda3/envs/new_env'. Check that you have sufficient permissions.`

I tried to install only `tensorflow-gpu` in this new environment, but I got the following error:

`conda install tensorflow-gpu

DirectoryNotACondaEnvironmentError: The target directory exists, but it is not a conda environment.
Use 'conda create' to convert the directory to a conda environment.
target directory: /home/.../anaconda3/envs/tf-gp`

And when I try the way that it was explained I got the following error:

`CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /home/..../anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu`

CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /home/..../anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu`

Now I don't know How I should resolve this problem. Indeed my goal was installing `tensorflow` using `conda` but not in a `new environment` because I had `pythorch` installed and I had some jupyter notebooks that I wanted to import `tensorflow` and use some specific libraries.
But I fall into a loop of installing and uninstalling that led to this wired problem. The problem is that I can't reinstall `tensorflow` in the environment that I had created and removed `tensorflow` from it because it says the `environment` is not a `conda environment` and when I try to convert the `environment` to a `conda environment` I get the error of `prefix`. And when I try to create a `new environment` I get the error of `permission`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The problem solved by the follwoing command:`touch  /home/.../anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/conda-meta/history`

Answer (score 0):

Conda creates folders for the environments under `~/miniconda3/envs/` by default. Try navigating to this folder and manually deleting the `tensorflow-gpu` folder then try again. (If you installed a different version of conda or put it in a different location, navigate to the appropriate location and delete the `tensorflow-gpu` folder in `.../envs/`.)

Sometimes I have the issue where conda doesn't quite remove everything and manually deleting the folder fixes it.